# Reference a window with a designated name

Tags: window, frames

I list the current windows with

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :tangle yes
(window-list)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
| #<window 14 on 28.Windows.org> | #<window 3 on .emacs.d> |
```

Then I tried to operate one of them with

```
(split-window '#<window 14 on 28.Windows.org>)
```

but get the error:

```
Symbol’s value as variable is void: on
```

Tried alternatively

```
(split-window #<window 14 on 28.Windows.org>)
(split-window <window 14 on 28.Windows.org>)
```

Report the same error,

How could I reference a window by a designated name?

Comment: Please consider removing all of the extraneous Org stuff from the question. You don't need to show Org syntax to show Lisp code. Thx.

Comment: ... and in this case, it obfuscates the fact that `(window-list)` returns a `list` - on which you can apply functions like `nth` in order to select and operate on a particular element, e.g.: `(split-window (nth 0 (window-list)))` will happily split the first window in the list.

Comment: @NickD ty, amazing solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What Org emits here is a printed representation of an otherwise opaque window object.  While you can serialize a window to a string, you cannot go back from the string to the window.  You can recognize such data types by their printed representation looking like `#<...>`, see https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Printed-Representation.html for further details.

This doesn't mean that you can't do meaningful things with windows though.  For example the following works just fine:

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :tangle yes
(split-window (selected-window))
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: #<window 38>
```

Comment: Is Org relevant here? If not, how about removing it?

Comment: To expand a bit on what @wasamasa said, it may not be obvious that you can store that opaque object in a variable: `(setq foo (selected-window)) (split-window foo)`

Answer (score 2):

If you use [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) then you can use command `icicle-select-window` to switch to windows by name, using completion.

> **`icicle-select-window`** is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
>   [`icicles-cmd1.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/icicles-cmd1.el).
>
> `(icicle-select-window)`
>
> Select window by its name.
>
> With no prefix arg, candidate windows are those of the selected frame.
>
> With a prefix arg:
>
> - Non-negative means windows of all visible frames are candidates.
> - Negative means windows of all frames are candidates (i.e., including
>     iconified and invisible frames).
>
> A window name is the name of its displayed buffer, but suffixed as
>   needed by `[`*`NUMBER`*`]`, to make the name unique.  For example, if you have
>   two windows showing buffer *Help*, one of the windows will be called
>   `*Help*[2]` for use with this command.

Answer (score 2):

Build on the icicle answer you can do that without including this big library with that function:

```lisp
(defun MY/select-window-by-name (name)
  "Selects the window with buffer NAME"
  (select-window
   (car (seq-filter
     (lambda (window)
       (equal name (buffer-name (window-buffer window))))
     (window-list-1 nil 0 t)))))
```